# How to compute the expected standard deviation of a multinomial distribution?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation, multinomial-distribution

Given is a [multinomial  distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with $k$ mutually exclusive events with probabilities $p_1, .., p_k$. We draw a sample of size $n$ and get sample sizes $s_1, .., s_k$. The expected value for each event is $np_i$. If I want a single parameter to evaluate how far away my sample is from the expected value I need to consider the values $s_i - np_i$ and combine them with some norm. I want to use the $L^1$-norm (the $L^2$ norm or some others could also be suitable), so I define the distance of my sample from the expected value to be:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^k |s_i - np_i| $$

**What is the expected value of this quantity?**

For one of the events the standard deviation is just $\sqrt{np_i(1-p_i)}$ so a naive first guess might be the sum of these but the events are not independent so this doesn't work.

The covariance matrix of a multinomial distribution can be easily computed with $p_i(1-p_i)$ on the diagonal and $-p_ip_j$ off the diagonal and I feel there should be a simple formula for the expected standard deviation using this matrix but I can't find it.

Note that in the simplest case where $k=2$ this simplifies to a binomial distribution and the expected standard deviation is $2\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.

The application of this is testing with a sample whether the assumed distribution is indeed the correct one. So you assume you have a fair dice, through it a bunch of times and then check whether the sample you got is consistent with a fair dice or whether the sample seems highly unlikely with a fair dice and you have a strong suspicion that the dice is not fair.

Comment: If you are using an $L^1$ norm, then you should probably not be talking about standard deviations.

Comment: I would have thought that $\mathbb E \left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (s_i - np_i)^2\right] = n\sum\limits_{i=1}^k p_i (1-p_i)$

Comment: I would also have thought that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{(s_i - np_i)^2}{np_i}$ might have a distribution approximately like a $\chi^2_{k-1}$ distribution, as used with Pearson's chi-squared test

Comment: So you second post says that if I use the $L^2$ norm instead of the $L^1$ norm I can just add the variances. That sounds plausible, I will have to think about that. It also seems relatively straightforward to test numerically.

Comment: Indeed I think you can say $\mathbb E \left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (s_i - np_i)^2\right] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \mathbb E \left[(s_i - np_i)^2\right]$ by linearity of expectation even if you do not have independence.  But this does not tell you about the distribution of this statistic, for which the lack of  independence will matter